# How to Remove special character(\) from my 2d list?

Tags: python, list

Input

```
input = [['Is the world population still growing?\', \'Is the world population the same as the human population?\', "Is the world\'s population still growing?", \'Are there still 2 billion people living in the world?']]
```

output

```
output = [['Is the world population still growing?', 'Is the world population the same as the human population?', 'Is the worlds population still growing?', 'Are there still 2 billion people living in the world?']]
```

Comment: your desired output is not valid python

Comment: I want just remove \ from my list. is it possible ?

Comment: By the way, there is not really a \ character in the string from your list. The \ that you see is called an escape character. It tells the interpreter: "Don't interpret the following single quote as a quote to delimit a string, but as a character that is part of the string. You can run ```print(input[0][0])``` to see what I mean.

Comment: To complete my previous comment, note that there is only one string in the input nested list, while the output nested list contains four strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
output = [re.split('[\'"], [\'"]', input[0][0])]
```

What is going on here?

1. `input[0][0]` is simply the string located inside the `input` nested list.
2. The `'[\'"], [\'"]'` string literal creates the following string: `['"], ['"]`. In this context, it has to be interpreted as a [regular expression](https://regexr.com/) that will match any string that is:

   - a single or double quote,
   - followed by a comma,
   - followed by a space,
   - followed by a single or double quote.

   Note that we have to use a backslash `\` before the single quotes, or else the interpreter will assume we wanted to mark the end of our string literal. So the backslashes are just [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), they are not actually included in the string.
3. re.split takes the `input[0][0]` string and splits it into a list of strings, using as splitting points all substrings that match the regular expression described in 2 above.
4. Finally, the list output from 3 is nested in an outer list and assigned to `output` (to match the requirements set out in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example solution using `replace()` function:

```
i = """Is the world population still growing?\ """
print(i.replace("\\", ""))
```

**Output**

```
Is the world population still growing?
```